# Django error: The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing?

Tags: python, django, many-to-many, django-related-manager

I have the following models schema:

```py
class Site(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    location = models.OneToOneField(GeoLocation, on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                                    related_name=RelatedNames.ADDRESS,
                                    blank=True, null=True)

    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name=RelatedNames.ACCOUNT_SITES)
    _type = models.IntegerField(choices=SiteTypeChoices.CHOICES)
    primary_email = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)

    objects = models.Manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_site_address(self):
        return str(self.location)


class SiteScore(models.Model):
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name=RelatedNames.SITE_SCORES)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    score_type = models.IntegerField(choices=SiteScoreChoices.CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)

class CustomUser(AbstractUser)
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_(Fields.EMAIL_ADDRESS), unique=True)

    accessed_sites = models.ManyToManyField(Site, related_name=RelatedNames.USERS)
    
    USERNAME_FIELD = Fields.EMAIL
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
```

I'm trying to filter out the site scores by date and by the user connected to the sites:

```py
today = timezone.now().date()
worst_scores = SiteScore.objects.filter(date__date=today, site__users=self.request.user).order_by('-score')
```

But this raises this error:

```
The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing.
```

Also tried using:

```py
        worst_scores = SiteScore.objects.filter(date__date=today, site__users__in=self.request.user)
```

But got error:

```
'CustomUser' object is not iterable
```

Comment: you may wanna check [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

Comment: Is `today` a queryset? Can you clarify what it represents?

Comment: @AzyCrw4282 today is a datetime object, I'll update the code

Comment: @yovelcohen if possible do add a comment on the answer as to which solution worked- It may help future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Few possible solutions**

The

```
date__date=today
```

is returning a result > 1 and as such it fails. Can you try and pass a more accurate today object (e.g.custom formed) and check if that works?

What happens for this

```
worst_scores = SiteScore.objects.filter(date__date=today, site__users=self.request.user).order_by('-score')[0]
```

Try using the `.get()` instead of `filter()` if you want to filter by just one particular item.

For several, you can use the  `__in`, e.g.

```
products = Product.objects.filter(seller__in=account)
```

so with the [**`__in`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in).

Comment: I changed a few things, first I was using a datetime instead of only date which failed it, using that along witht the in opeartor fix my case